# How do I increase the size of swapfile without removing it in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, files, swap, storage

Is there a way to increase my existing "swapfile" without having to destroy and re-create it?
I would like to up my swap space from 1GB to 2GB.  Currently it is set up as such:

```
$ sudo swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile               file        1048572 736640  -1
$ ls -lh /swapfile
-rw------- 1 root root 1.0G Nov  9  2016 /swapfile
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: How much RAM do you have? Is 2G enough? I think that you'll have to `swapoff`, create a new /swapfile, `mkswap`, and `swapon -a`

Comment: Add a new swap file, follow the instruction of the above question. you can have 2 swap file ;)

Comment: @Ravexina, A newbie question perhaps, but why would I want to add a new swap file rather than increasing the size of the existing one?  Or is it not possible to increase an existing swap file?

Comment: @Dave That's possible too, as you may know we can `swapoff` then `dd` and `mkswap` finally `swapon`. I thought you don't want to touch your file.

Comment: @Ravexina, I don't want to destroy the swapfile.  If what your suggesting destroys the swapfile but is the only way, I'm in.

Comment: @Dave why you don't want to remove it ? is there any spacial reason?

Comment: «why you don't want to remove it» In my case it's to use hibernation. Because I have to put the resume_offset in my kernel params in grub.cfg which wound change if the file was recreated. Also hibernation can use only one swapfile so add another swapfile won't do it.

Answer (score 226, accepted):

First disable swap file:

```
sudo swapoff /swapfile
```

Now let's increase the size of swap file:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=1024 oflag=append conv=notrunc
```

The above command will append 1GiB of zero bytes at the end of your swap file.

Setup the file as a "swap file":

```
sudo mkswap /swapfile
```

enable swaping:

```
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

---

On a production system, if your operating system does not let you to disable the swap file using `sudo swapoff /swapfile` and you receive a messages similar to:

```
swapoff failed: Cannot allocate memory
```

Then You might consider having multiple swap files or create a new larger one, initialize it and then remove the old smaller one.

Comment: `sudo fallocate -l 2G /swapfile` is probably safer than dd (although it doesn't keep the original swapfile), and it also needs a `sudo chmod 600 /swapfile`.

Comment: @heynnema Doesn't `fallocate` make sparse files? The `swapon` manpage says sparse swap files are problematic (specifically mentioning `fallocate`).

Comment: @muru I think the answer is yes, it creates sparse files, "as preallocation is done quickly by allocating blocks and marking them as uninitialized, requiring no IO to  the  data blocks"... but then the `mkswap` command should take care of that, no? The big concern with this dd example is if the user enters a space before the "swapfile", and wipes their root.

Comment: @heynnema no, the `mkswap` manpage also says that the files should not contain any holes.

Comment: @muru **guess I'm wrong :-)** Every time that I read how to create a /swapfile with the onset of 17.04 they used fallocate. I guess that we'll just have to use "disk destroyer"!

Comment: @heynnema: What you could do is to use `fallocate` to pre-allocate disk space and then use `dd` to fill the holes with zeros.

Comment: Just did this in Linux Mint, with it running, and it went (slow to `swapoff`, but) smoothly. I've increased from 2GB to 9GB (8GB RAM + 1GB spare for whatever may be needed)

Comment: [Mint should really ask the user for the swap size on setup](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=339771), especially when it creates a swap *partition*.

Comment: @muru, great points about `fallocate` and the man pages. I've just cited you and added that information to [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1177620/327339). I was about to update my answer just now to use `fallocate` instead of `dd`, since it's supposed to be much faster, but then I realized my mistake as I scanned this page for `fallocate` and found your comments.

Comment: This answer obviously does not address the question at all.

Comment: @DustWolf What you were looking for?

Comment: @Ravexina see the OP question or title.

Comment: @DustWolf The answer provides a solution to increase the swap file without removing it from the terminal. Exactly what the title is asking. What else should it supply so it can be considered the correct answer?

Comment: @Ravexina `swapoff` removes the swap.

Comment: @DustWolf You and OP have different definition of remove! they meant without removing the file! that's why they marked the question as the correct one. What you are asking for is a totally different question though I have touched it in my answer.

Comment: note that if the swapfile does not exist, this command will also create it

Answer (score 114):

You should add a new swapfile instead of resizing the exist one **because it costs you nothing to do so**. To resize a swapfile, you must first disable it, which evicts the swap contents to RAM, which increases pressure on RAM and may even summon the OOM killer (not to mention that you could possibly be thrashing your disks for several minutes). Multiple swap files are not a problem, it's trivially easy to setup yet another swap file. There's quite literally no benefit to resizing a swap file over adding another.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/some/file count=1K bs=1M
mkswap /some/file
sudo chown root:root /some/file
sudo chmod 600 /some/file
sudo swapon /some/file
```

This command creates a file of size 1 gigabyte. `count` is the size of the file in block size, which is set by the `bs` flag, in bytes. Here, `bs` is set to `1M` (= 2^20 bytes, 1 megabyte (MiB)), when multiplied by `1K` ( = 1024) is 1 GiB (1 gigabyte).

Comment: Is the `sudo chmod 600 /some/file` required, or no?

Comment: And does `count=1K` give a 1G file? count is in block size, yes? And that can be 512/4096? Or is my math wrong?

Comment: @heynnema 1K*1M is 1G, so yes, it gives a 1G file. It can be whatever you want it to be. Once the swapfile is activated, you can't normally write to it or modify it (only root can, IIRC, so permissions wouldn't matter anyway).

Comment: +1 This approach also makes it easy to disconnect one of the swapfiles if you later decide you need the disk space back.

Comment: @mgarey: Only you and the mods can delete your comments and I am neither you nor a mod.

Comment: This really needs to be marked as the correct answer. Wow, bravo!

Comment: Just as a note, I had to `sudo` all 5 lines

Comment: @muru is this suppose to be a permanent solution? I performed these command on April 30th, but in sometime in the month of May, my second swapfile was gone. I didn't delete but it was gone

Comment: After reboot, in my Ubuntu 18.04, the system reverted to using the old swapfile instead of the new swapfile. I had to update `/etc/fstab` as mentioned by @borekon in his answer: `echo '/swapfile none swap sw 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab`.

Comment: «because it costs you nothing to do so» Except for hibernation. «The suspend image cannot span multiple swap partitions and/or swap files. It must fully fit in one swap partition or one swap file.[» https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate

Comment: Actual source: «Q: Does swsusp (to disk) use only one swap partition or can it use
multiple swap partitions (aggregate them into one logical space)?

A: Only one swap partition, sorry.» https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/swsusp.txt

Comment: @tuxayo eh, Hibernation is iffy enough on Linux that I don't imagine it does cost nothing. In any case, it says " It must fully fit in one swap partition or one swap file", not that if there are multiple swap files it will refuse it fit into whichever one is large enough to accomodate it.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on `/some/file`?

Comment: @muru My message was too vague, if the need to have more swap space is to hibernate, then when adding another swapfile, then it must be setup as the hibernation one. Including getting the resume_offset and adding to kernel boot params, which is also needed when destroying and recreating. So when using hibernation it's likely the more convenient to resize instead of add a swapfile or recreate.

Answer (score 45):

*(this answer completely rewritten since the downvote)*

### Notes about `fallocate` vs `dd`

Before we continue, I want to point out that some answers use `fallocate` to allocate space for a file, instead of `dd`. *Don't do that. Use `dd`.* [@muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru) pointed out some important points [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927854/how-do-i-increase-the-size-of-swapfile-without-removing-it-in-the-terminal/1177620#comment1467666_927870) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927854/how-do-i-increase-the-size-of-swapfile-without-removing-it-in-the-terminal/1177620#comment1467669_927870). Although `fallocate` is much much faster, it may create files with holes. I think that simply means the space is not contiguous, which is bad for swap files. I picture this as meaning that `fallocate` creates a C-style linked-list of memory, whereas `dd` creates a C-array contiguous block of memory. Swap files need a contiguous block. `dd` does this by doing a byte-for-byte copy of binary zeros from the `/dev/zero` pseudo-file into a new file it generates.

`man swapon` also states *not* to use `fallocate`, and to use `dd` instead. Here is the quote (emphasis added):

> NOTES
>
> You should not use `swapon` on a file with holes.  This can be seen in
> the system log as
>
> ```bash
> swapon: swapfile has holes.
> ```
>
> The  swap  file  implementation  in the kernel expects to be able to
> write to the file directly, without the assistance of  the  filesystem.   ***This  is a problem* on preallocated files (e.g.  `fallocate(1)`) on filesystems like `XFS` or `ext4`, and  on  copy-on-write  filesystems like `btrfs`**.
>
> **It  is  recommended to use `dd(1)` and `/dev/zero` to avoid holes on XFS and ext4.**

And from `man mkswap` (emphasis added):

> Note  that  a  swap file must not contain any holes.  Using `cp(1)` to
> create the file is not acceptable.  Neither is use  of  `fallocate(1)`
> on  file  systems  that  support  preallocated files, such as **XFS** or
> **ext4**, or on copy-on-write filesystems like **btrfs**.  **It is recommended to  use  `dd(1)` and `/dev/zero` in these cases.  Please read notes from `swapon(8)` before adding a swap file to copy-on-write filesystems.**

So, **use `dd`, *not* `fallocate`**, to create the swap files.

### Option 1 (my preference): delete the old swap file and create a new one of the correct size:

Rather than *resizing* the swap file, just delete it and create a new one at the appropriate size!

```bash
swapon --show               # see what swap files you have active
sudo swapoff /swapfile      # disable /swapfile
# Create a new 16 GiB swap file in its place (could lock up your computer 
# for a few minutes if using a spinning Hard Disk Drive [HDD], so be patient)
# (Ex: on 15 May 2023, this took 3 min 3 sec on a 5400 RPM 750 GB 
# model HGST HTS541075A9E680 SATA 2.6, 3.0Gb/s HDD in an old laptop of mine)
time sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile count=16 bs=1G
sudo mkswap /swapfile       # turn this new file into swap space
sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile   # only let root read from/write to it, for security
sudo swapon /swapfile       # enable it
swapon --show               # ensure it is now active
```

In case you are adding this swap file for the first time, ensure it is in your `/etc/fstab` file to make the swap file available again after each reboot. Just run these two commands:

```bash
# Make a backup copy of your /etc/fstab file just in case you
# make any mistakes
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak

# Add this swapfile entry to the end of the file to re-enable
# the swap file after each boot
echo '/swapfile none swap sw 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

Source: see the ["Step 4: Make the changes permanent" section here](https://itsfoss.com/create-swap-file-linux/).

### Option 2: resize the old swap file:

The [accepted answer by @Ravexina](https://askubuntu.com/a/927870/327339) is correct. However, initially I didn't understand all of its pieces, so I wanted to include some more descriptions and explain more of the details. See `dd --help` and `man dd`. Some of my learning on this comes from [Bogdan Cornianu's blog post](https://bogdancornianu.com/change-swap-size-in-ubuntu/) as well. I also add a few commands at the end to show how to verify your swap space once you create it.

### How to resize swap file:

Here we will *increase* the size of the existing swap file by writing 8 GiB ([Gibibytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte)) of zeros to the end of it.

1. Turn off usage of just this one swap file (located at "**/swapfile**"):

   ```bash
    # Do this
    sudo swapoff /swapfile

    # NOT this, which unnecessarily disables all swap files or partitions
    # sudo swapoff --all
    # or
    # sudo swapoff -a
   ```
2. Increase the size of the swap file by 8 GiB by appending all zero bytes to the end of it (rather than rewriting the whole file, which would be slower):

   ```bash
    sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=8 oflag=append conv=notrunc
   ```

   - `if` = input file
   - `/dev/zero` = a special Linux "file" which just outputs all zero bytes every time you read from it
   - `of` = output file
   - `bs` = block size

     - Here, `1G` stands for 1 Gibibyte, or GiB, which is the base-2 version of "Gigabyte, which is base-10. According to `man dd`, `G =1024*1024*1024` bytes. This is how I like to size files since computers and hardware memory are base-2.
     - If you'd like to use 1 Gigabyte, or GB, which is the base-10 version of "Gibibyte", which is base-2, then you must instead use `1GB` rather than `1G`. `man dd` shows that `GB =1000*1000*1000` bytes.
   - `count` = multiplier of blocks; the total memory written will be `count * bs`.
   - `oflag=append` means to *append* to the end of the output file, rather than rewriting the whole thing. See `dd --help` and `man dd`. From `dd --help`:

     > ```bash
     > append    append mode (makes sense only for output; conv=notrunc suggested)
     > ```
   - `conv=notrunc` means when "converting" the file, "do not truncate the output file"; `dd --help`, as you can see just above, shows this is recomended whenever doing `oflag=append`
   - **Note:** if you wanted to *rewrite* the whole swap file rather than just appending to it, you could create a 32 GiB swapfile like this, for example:

     ```bash
       sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=32
     ```
3. Make the file usable as swap

   ```bash
    sudo mkswap /swapfile
   ```
4. Turn on the swap file

   ```bash
    sudo swapon /swapfile
   ```
5. **(Bonus/Optional):** ensure this swap file you just created is now in usage:

   ```bash
    swapon --show
   ```

   Sample output:

   > ```bash
   > $ swapon --show
   > NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
   > /swapfile file  64G 1.8G   -2
   > ```

   You can also look at some memory/swap info with these two commands as well:

   ```bash
    # 1. Examine the /proc/meminfo file for entries named "swap", such 
    # as the "SwapTotal" line
    cat /proc/meminfo | grep -B 1000 -A 1000 -i swap

    # 2. Look at total memory (RAM) and swap (virtual memory) used
    # and free:
    free -h
   ```

### References:

1. [@Ravexina's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/927870/327339)
2. Bogdan Cornianu's blog post here: https://bogdancornianu.com/change-swap-size-in-ubuntu/
3. "How to Create and Use Swap File on Linux": https://itsfoss.com/create-swap-file-linux/

### See also:

1. My answer where I use the above information about increasing your swapfile size in order to solve an out-of-memory Bazel build error: [Stack Overflow: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when running bazel build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60572662/4561887)

Comment: To the downvoter, I just massively rewrote this answer to make it expound upon and add new information to the knowledge-base already provided in the existing answers. I think it adds value now.

Comment: I now have two swapfiles, one in /dev/sda2 and /swapfile. Which one will debian catch up for hibernate? With `pm-hibernate` I get Failed to hibernate system via logind: Access denied Failed to start hibernate.target: Unit hibernate.target is masked. Before the swapfile creation I got Failed to hibernate system via logind: Not enough swap space for hibernation

Comment: @Timo, any active swap file can be used, I believe. What does `swapon --show` show? Which of those two swap files is active? If both, the system can decide what to use and how, I assume, using both perhaps simultaneously even, as it sees fit.

Comment: great, I get `/swapfile file   8G 36.3M   -2` with swapon. But the error remain, access denied.

Comment: @Timo, try asking a new question on AskUbuntu. Paste a link here to your question so we can help if able.

Comment: This answer should be the best :). thks to you i did this very simple

Comment: Solid answer, clear and well documented.

Answer (score 31):

You can create another swap file as i did:

1. `sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile`
2. `sudo chmod 600 /swapfile`
3. `sudo mkswap /swapfile`
4. `sudo swapon /swapfile`
5. Verify it is working with `sudo swapon --show`
   To make it permanent add a file to the `fstab`file typing:
   `echo '/swapfile none swap sw 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab`

Comment: Please note that `fallocate`should bit be used to create the file, as it creates a sparce file.  see `man mkswap`

Comment: @CharlesGreen it worked me as i wrote, so it should work for almos anyone.

Comment: I would sugegst reading `man mkswap`, especially the last pargraph before "Environment"

Comment: worked on NanoPi Neo with Armbian v 5.65

Comment: Wouldn't cost a lot to add "swapoff /swapfile" as the first command because the question is about increasing the swapfile size.

Comment: As of kernel 5.7 swap files created with fallocate will not always work, and dd is the recommended solution. Ex: "sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096 status=progress". See https://man.archlinux.org/man/swapon.8#Files_with_holes

Answer (score 6):

I have good results on my Ubuntu 17.04 following the advice of Arian Acosta from the [blogpost](https://arianacosta.com/linux/resizing-swap-file-with-bash/). One can substitute the 4G here `sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile` with any amount of gigabytes you want. For example `sudo fallocate -l 2G /swapfile` for TS.

> Generally speaking, the recommended size for a swap file is 2X the amount of RAM, but you can make it as big as you need. Remember that this is not a substitute for memory because performance is much worse since things are stored in the disk.
>
> I’ve created a simple bash script that increments the swap file to 4GB and tested it on Ubuntu 16.04.
>
> This can be run line by line or a bash script, but I use it to make headless installations.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "====== Current Swap ======"
sudo swapon -s
echo "====== Turning Off Swap ======"
sudo swapoff /swapfile
echo "====== Allocating 4GB Swap ======"
sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile
echo "====== Making Swap ======"
sudo mkswap /swapfile
echo "====== Setting Permissions to Root Only  ======"
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
echo "====== Turning On Swap ======"
sudo swapon /swapfile
echo "====== Current Swap ======"
sudo swapon -s
echo "====== Done! ======"
```

Comment: You should have added an argument to the script, which is the amount of SWAP to be added and finally add it to fstab. But still, i like this

Comment: As of kernel 5.7 swap files created with fallocate will not always work, and dd is the recommended solution. Ex: "sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096 status=progress". See https://man.archlinux.org/man/swapon.8#Files_with_holes

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to check permissions. Other way to do this:

```
# check your swap
free

# turn off swap
sudo swapoff /swapfile

# To create the SWAP file, you will need to use this.
sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile  # same as "sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=4"

# Secure swap.
sudo chown root:root /swapfile
sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile

# Prepare the swap file by creating a Linux swap area.
sudo mkswap /swapfile

# Activate the swap file.
sudo swapon /swapfile

# Confirm that the swap partition exists.
sudo swapon -s

# check your swap again
free
```

Comment: Answer removes swap, e.g. not what the OP asked.