# Ubuntu 18.04: Swap is not active after I increased its size

Tags: 18.04, swap

I increased the swap size from 4 GB to 19.8 GB and after that it is not swaping anymore (0 bytes). I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031300/977215).

Thanks

Comment: From the answer You provided first step should be disabling swap `swapoff /swapfile` and at the end enabling it again `swapon /swapfile`. What is the output of `sudo swapon --show` ?

Comment: @michal-przybylowicz, `/nvme0n1p5 partition 3,8G   0B   -2
/swapfile      file       16G   0B   -3
`

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165477/no-swapping-on-lubuntu-at-enabled-swap