# Swap file size for 8GB of ram

Tags: 18.04, ram, swap

I just purchased a root server from a web hosting provider, where I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. 
 
My server has an HDD of 320 GB SAS and 8 GB of RAM, and would host a Twitter-like web application.
What size would you suggest for a swap file? Would a swap file as big as the amount of RAM be too much? A more than one year old [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-18-04) from Digital Ocean says that "Generally, an amount equal to or double the amount of RAM on your system is a good starting point. Another good rule of thumb is that anything over 4G of swap is probably unnecessary if you are just using it as a RAM fallback". Of course, 16 GB seem too much. What is your opinion?

Comment: Happily, [changing the size of your swapfile](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927854/how-do-i-increase-the-size-of-swapfile-without-removing-it-in-the-terminal) after install is pretty easy, so this is not a world-shaking decision for you. Go with what makes you comfortable, and adjust later if needed.

Answer (score 1):

The [authoritative recommendation from Red Hat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/ch-swapspace#tb-recommended-system-swap-space) suggests 8GB of swap file for 8GB of RAM, which is pretty much netter than my opinion.

However, although you did not mention, if you are using Hibernation in Ubuntu, a swap partition equal to the amount of RAM is needed (op cit.).