# Can't add swap memory permanently on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: swap, fstab

I am trying to add the swap memory and I've succeeded in doing it temporarily, but it fails when I try to do it permanently by using /etc/fstab. Could you explain, what I am doing wrong? Here are the steps, that I do on the clean Ubuntu 20.4 server installed:

```
fallocate -l 1G /swapfile2
chmod 600 /swapfile2
mkswap /swapfile2
swapon /swapfile2
```

And this works. When I go with

```
free -m
```

I see, that the swap memory is allocated.
But when add it to /etc/fstab by adding the string:

```
/swapfile2 none swap sw 0 0
```

And then disabling the swap and trying to mount it from fstab

```
swapoff -a
mount -a
```

I get no swap memory in the free -m output.

Any ideas, why can it work like that?

Comment: I am not sure that `mount -a` will remount swap. You might have to use `sqapon -a`  or similar, Swap should remount after reboot though.

Comment: The correct command would be `swapon -a`.  Please note however, that the `fallocate` command may produce a swapfile with holes in it and be invalid.  It is preferred to use `dd` to create the swapfile - see `man swapon`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I increase the size of swapfile without removing it in the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927854/how-do-i-increase-the-size-of-swapfile-without-removing-it-in-the-terminal)

Comment: @guiverc, yes, I've edited my question, thank you

Comment: @CharlesGreen no

Comment: @CharlesGreen thank you, this answeres my question